# Solving a system of equations with Matlab/Mupad

Tags: matlab

I need to evaluate the transfer function of a circuit i.e. the output voltage (vo)/input current (is). I was wondering if  Matlab/ Mupad has a functionality to do this without using numerical values (I need a symbolic equation). It is kind of like solving the following system of equations, where the variable v1 needs to be eliminated.

-is = v1/R1 + v1Cs +(v1-v0)Cs

vo =  a long complicated eqted equation that also contains v1

Thanks for any help!

Comment: you can use `syms` to define the variables in your equation, and then use `solve` to find the solution to the (set of) equations.

Comment: you equation is not clear. Is `s` the laplace variable? is `Cs` a sigle variable or is it `C*s`? can you rewrite the equation making sure you put all the *? I guess `vo` and `v0` are the same variable?

Comment: @Ander : 
Yes s is the laplace variable (1/C*s being the capacitor impedance.)
Tes vo and v0 are the same variable, Sorry about that. I have retyped the equations below:

-is = v1/r1 + v1*C1*s + (v1-vo)Cs 

gm*v1 + vo/r2 + vo*C*s +vo*C2*s = 0;

What I need to get is the ration (vo/is). 

Wouter Kuijsters : Can solve be used to find the ratio? I did manage to use solve to find is and vo individually (in mupad), but the equations looked a bit unwieldy - I was wondering if there is an exact solution that can be obtained.